# How to add DSL Forge to my Eclipse Java EE Mars?

Tags: eclipse

I need to add DSL Forge to my Eclipse Java EE Mars because I want to create a project like this:

[image: this image clear to what kind of project I want]

I want to generate web editor from Xtext.

Comment: simpy doing this http://dslforge.org/download/ does not work?

Comment: No , not work ... I follow it step by step and dose not work

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: can you give a step by step description of what you do?

Comment: Step one : from Help -> install New software then I type the url to download Dsl Forge tooling step tow : from Help -> install New software then I type the url to download Dsl Forge runtime ... after that when I open eclipse and make new project I don't found Dsl Forge  to creat web editor xtext

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this

1. have java 8 as default or adapt eclipse.ini to use it after downloading
2. download mars jee (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/mars2)
3. start the downloaded eclipse
4. Help -> Install new software
5. Add "Dsl Forge" -> "http://dslforge.org/downloads/tooling/repository/"
6. Select "DSL Forge Tools Feature"
7. next/finish
8. restart
9. file -> new project -> DSL Forge

btw the docs say you should install xtext 2.10 (http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/)

Comment: I follow your steps step by step , but after restart in step 8 I can't find DSL Forge in file ->new project ... I install xtext2.10 and do restart ... also I can't find DSL Forge in file ->new project

Comment: try: (1) open console (2) select host osgi console on the open console button (3) type ss org.dslforge (enter)
what is the result of this?

Comment: How I can open console?

Comment: and ss xtext? or ss forge?. which java version do you start your eclipse with? maybe the plugins require java 8 but you use java 7

Comment: In the help installation detail configuration a should be a info which vm is used

Comment: I use jre 7 , I must to change it to jre 8 to work the plugins ?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score 0):

To generate the web editor from Xtext, you need to be on Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers.

> If you want a closer integration with Xtext and EMF, or if you want to integrate the editor with other Eclipse components, you’d better install Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers. This makes it possible to integrate the editor with third party RWT (Remote Widget Toolkit, the web-based SWT) plugins and widgets.

Now if it's mandatory for you to develop on Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, you'll need to install the RAP Tools before DSL Forge (this is somehow a hybrid scenario). See also the pre-requisites in the documentation: http://dslforge.org/getting-started-generate-xtext-rap-editor/